Weight space decomposition of smooth representation of complex algebraic torus
Question: Let $T=(\mathbb{C}^{*})^{n}$ and $\pi:\mathcal{E}\to \mathbb{C}^{n}$ a smooth complex $T$-equivariant vector bundle (i.e. $\pi$ is $T$-equivariant and $T$ acts on the fibers linearly). The space of global sections $\Gamma(\mathbb{C}^{n},\mathcal{E})$ is a smooth representation of $T$. Is there a weight space decomposition
$$\Gamma(\mathbb{C}^{n},\mathcal{E})=\bigoplus_{\chi}\Gamma(\mathbb{C}^{n},\mathcal{E})_{\chi} $$ where $\chi$ runs over smooth characters of $T$?
Here a smooth character of $T$ is defined as follows [IFM12] section 2): For $\mu=(b+\sqrt{-1}c,v)\in \mathcal{R}:=\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{Z}, g^{\mu}:=|g|^{b+\sqrt{-1}c}(\frac{g}{|g|})^{v}$ for $g\in \mathbb{C}^{*}$. For $\alpha=(\alpha^{1},\dotsc,\alpha^{n})\in \mathcal{R}^{n},\chi^{\alpha}(g_{1},\dotsc,g_{n}):=\prod_{k=1}^{n}g_{k}^{\alpha^{k}}$.
Any hint or reference is appreciated.
Background: For a toric vector bundle $\pi:\mathcal{E}\to X(\sigma)$ over a toric variety $X$, we have (e.g. [Payne08] section 2)
$$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})=\bigoplus_{u\in M}\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})_{u}$$
where $M$ is the character lattice and $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})_{u}=\{s\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{E}) \mid t\cdot s=\chi^{u}(t)s \text{ } \forall t\in T \}$ where $T$ is the same as above.
Motivation: I am trying to prove triviality of smooth complex $T$-equivariant vector bundle over an "affine" piece of a topological toric manifold by mimicking Klyachko's proof of triviality of toric vector bundles over affine toric varieties [Kly90] where the existence of this weight space decomposition is crucial. This decomposition in the algebraic setting was proved in Mumford's book on GIT, but in the smooth setting I don't know any tools available to prove or disprove it for lack of knowledge of infinite dimensional representation theory.

Welcome new contributor.  There is the Peter-Weyl theorem for the $L^2$-completion of the Frechet space of $C^{\infty}$ sections.  Is that what you want?

@JasonStarr Thank you for your comment. Is Peter-Weyl theorem applicable to non-compact group like $T$? Even after restricting to $(S^{1})^{n}$-action, how to guarantee that there is an inner product on the space of global sections to make the original representation unitary? If there is such inner product, does an $(S^{1})^{n}$-eigenspace coincide with a $T$-eigenspace?

@JasonStarr I know how to find the $L^{2}$-completion to make $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$ a unitary representation of $(S^{1})^{n}$. Could you give me more hint at the $T$-invariance of an $(S^{1})^{n}$-eigenspace?

We know a priori that every unitary irrep of the compact subgroup $(\textbf{U}_1)^n$ of the linear algebraic group $(\textbf{GL}1)^n$ is the restriction of an algebraic character $$\chi{e_1,\dots,e_n}:(\textbf{GL}_1)^n \to \textbf{GL}_1, \ (z_1,\dots,z_n) \mapsto z_1^{e_1}\cdots z_n^{e_n},$$ for a unique $(e_1,\dots,e_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n.$. For a unitary eigenvector $\vec{v}$ in a complex linear representation $V$, the holomorphic function, $$(\textbf{GL}_1)^n\to V, \ (z_1,\dots,z_n)\mapsto (z_1,\dots,z_n)\bullet \vec{v}-z_1^{e_1}\cdots z_n^{e_n}\vec{v}$$ vanishes on $(\textbf{U}_1)^n$.

Since $(\mathbf{U}_1)^n$ is Zariski dense, that function is identically zero.  Hence the decomposition into unitary irreps for the action of $(\mathbf{U}_1)^n$ gives the holomorphic decomposition into complex linear irreps of $(\mathbf{GL}_1)^n$.

This is a special case of Hermann Weyl's "Unitarian Trick."
